# Javascript : After sorting array, re-sort to compared

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I have two arrays like this;

```
var a = [5,3,1,2,4]
var val = [{id: 'no5'}, {id: 'no3'}, {id: 'no1'}, {id: 'no2'}, {id: 'no4'}]
```

They match each other index. `a[i] == val[i]`

However there are cases where I need to sort `a` so;

```
a.sort(function(a,b){ return a-b }) // a = [1,2,3,4,5]
```

My problem is, how do I re-index `a` so that it matches the index of `val`?

Comment: Why don't you make a copy of `a` before sorting it, so you can get the original version back?

Comment: Problem is, the values in a is changed after sorting. Just need to rearrange...

Comment: That's the point. Make a copy, and sort that. The original array will remain unchanged.

Comment: `0:99, 1:5, 2:1` after sort is `0:1, 1:5, 2:99`. I need to get 99 back to its original index. The value will be changed after I sort, so it's going to be a problem to compare...

Comment: That's why you make a COPY!!! Sorting the copy won't affect the original array.

Comment: Seems that you don't quite understand the problem. The array's values will change after it is being sorted, and needs to be re-indexed to its copy's index.

Answer (score 0):

```
val.sort(function(a,b){
    return a.id.slice(2) - b.id.slice(2);
});
```

EDIT: I misread the question, I thought OP wanted to sort `val` in the same way as `a`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm still not sure I understand, but I'll take a stab:

```
for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
    a[i] = parseInt(val[i].id.substr(2), 10);
}
```